# for each loop in handlebars is not working

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, handlebars.js, hbs

```
<section>
    <div class="container mt-5">
        <div class="row">
            {{#each products}}
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                    <img class="card-img-top"
                        src="{{this.image}}"
                        alt="Card image cap">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">{{this.name}}</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">{{this.description}}</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Add to Cart</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            {{/each}}
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

The code starts from `<div class="col-md-3">` is not working when I add **`{{#each products}}`**
Without the **`{{#each products}}`** it is working, Do anyone know about this?

Below is the declaration of array `products`.

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  let products=[
    {
      name: "iPhone 11",
      category: "Mobile",
      description: "Example",
      image: "https://www.apple.com/v/iphone-11/e/images/meta/og__f2jtwncwsl2e_specs.png"
    },
    {
      name: "OnePlus 9 Pro",
      category: "Mobile",
      description: "Example",
      image: "https://www.notebookcheck.net/uploads/tx_nbc2/4_zu_3_OnePlus_9_Pro.jpg"
    }
  ]
  res.render('index', {products});
});
```

When I run `{{log this}}` It gave me this -

```
{
  settings: {
    'x-powered-by': true,
    etag: 'weak',
    'etag fn': [Function: generateETag],
    env: 'development',
    'query parser': 'extended',
    'query parser fn': [Function: parseExtendedQueryString],
    'subdomain offset': 2,
    'trust proxy': false,
    'trust proxy fn': [Function: trustNone],
    view: [Function: View],
    views: 'My File Name',
    'jsonp callback name': 'callback',
    'view engine': 'hbs',
    port: 3000
  },
  products: [
    {
      name: 'iPhone 11',
      category: 'Mobile',
      description: 'This is a good phone',
      image: 'https://www.apple.com/v/iphone-11/e/images/meta/og__f2jtwncwsl2e_specs.png'
    },
    {
      name: 'OnePlus 9 Pro',
      category: 'Mobile',
      description: 'This is a good phone',
      image: 'https://www.notebookcheck.net/uploads/tx_nbc2/4_zu_3_OnePlus_9_Pro.jpg'
    }
  ],
  _locals: [Object: null prototype] {},
  cache: false
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you have an array called `products` and that it contains some elements? It may be helpful if you share an example data object you are passing to this template.

Comment: Yes, I have called an array and it contains objects. Please check in the question, I have added the array declaration.

Comment: It all looks perfectly valid to me. For example, see: https://jsfiddle.net/76484/qk4uezxt/

Comment: Yes Bro, But it is not showing the result in the body tag. It is fully blank in the body after the {{#each products}}

Comment: Something isn't connected correctly. Perhaps you could add `{{log this}}` to your template and see what is printed to the terminal in which you are running your node app.

Comment: Please Check the Question, I have updates

Comment: I don't think I can help you. Everything looks correct to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must end the `{{/each}}` before the 3rd `</div>` (from the last) that is, after `<div class="row"` I have started the `{{#each products}}`, so I had to end it before its closing tag. Below is the corrected code.

```
<section>
    <div class="container mt-5">
        <div class="row">
            {{#each products}}
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                    <img class="card-img-top"
                        src="{{this.image}}"
                        alt="Card image cap">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">{{this.name}}</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">{{this.description}}</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Add to Cart</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            {{/each}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `this` here
simply mentioning object's property name will do the work.

```js
<section>
    <div class="container mt-5">
        <div class="row">
            {{#each products}}
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                    <img class="card-img-top"
                        src="{{image}}"
                        alt="Card image cap">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">{{name}}</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">{{description}}</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Add to Cart</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            {{/each}}
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Hi, Bro I had a doubt on the {{#each products}}, that is, when i place that, rest of the elements in that will not show. Please can you tell the solution